# Assigning multiple properties to a Font

Tags: vb.net

I have some code in which I allow the user to control the different attributes of controls on a form, i.e. Italics, Bold, BackColor, ForeColor.

My problem is that when the user selects Italics & Bold, I'm not sure what the format is to do this. Here is what I have so far.

```
For Each ctl As Control In frm.Controls
   If TypeOf (ctl) Is Button Then
      ctl.Font = New Font(ctl.Font, FontStyle.Italic)
   End If
Next
```

This is the effect I want:

```
      ctl.Font = New Font(ctl.Font, FontStyle.Italic, FontStyle.Bold)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `Or` the two together:

```
ctl.Font = New Font(ctl.Font, FontStyle.Italic Or FontStyle.Bold)
```

Comment: @Blake Just tick the check next to my answer if it solved your problem, then it will be available to all that have a similar problem